# Delete dos folders 4 chars long starting with letter S

Tags: wildcard, dos, del, rmdir

I am trying to find a command, which could be described like

rmdir s???

i.e. delete all folders in current dir starting with S, exactly 4 characters long. I've tried rmdir, del, erase, none of them works. 
Any ideas please? Will it be different for empty and non-empty folders?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something similar to the first answer (in case of empty folders just remove the /s switch)

```
for /d %n in (s???) do rd  /s "%n"
```

Answer (score 1):

In MS-DOS 6.0 (per your question):

```
deltree/y s???
```

And in case you are not in MS-DOS but actually on the Windows command line:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /a:d /b s????') do rd /s /q %i
```